# assign macro variable output of tranwrd in macro function

Tags: sas

I can't figure out this seemingly trivial problem - expect macro variable to be assigned `mpg_city`.

```
%macro test(col=);
    %let id = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&col, 'extra_', ''));    
    %put &id;
%mend test;
%test(col=extra_mpg_city);
```

Current output is `extra_mpg_city`.

Comment: Also, if you're just creating macro variables you should look into a `data _null_ ` step and `CALL SYMPUTX()`. IMO it's usually a lot easier than messing around with macro functions. In general, you don't want to have too many macros cluttering your code it makes it harder to debug.

Comment: Best practice is to ensure your macro variables are localized within the macro (unless your coding design is working with global variables or within a framework) -- `%local id;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguments listed in a function invoked through `%sysfunc` are implicitly text and should not be quoted. Placing quotes in a `sysfunc` invoked function is like nesting quotes in a DATA step invocation.

Try

```
%let id = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&col, extra_, %str()));
```

The DATA Step analog is

```
id = tranwrd("&col", "extra_", "");
```

Your original code in DATA Step analog (below) should show why the `tranwrd` did not operate as you expected.

```
id = tranwrd("&col", "'extra_'", "''");
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the quotes when using string functions with `%sysfunc`, unless you expect to find them in the input. Try this:

```
%macro test(col=);
    %let id = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&col, extra_, ));    
    %put &id;
%mend test;
%test(col=extra_mpg_city);
```